# Floating shelf bracket using shorter metal prongs

Tags: shelving, load-bearing, anchor

I routed out 25cm long grooves in the center of the thickness of my floating ply shelves (3.4cm thickness). I have metal jumbo bolts of 12mm thickness and 25cm length that worked very well (the section in the wall expands when I twist the hexagonal cross section metal stud that extrudes from the wall. I ran out. I have same thickness but shorter length bolts that are identical except for the length (15cm). Cannot work out if the length should make any theoretical difference or it is purely the cross section thickness that determines load bearing here.
Thanks for any input

Comment: your description is pretty close to cryptic. ... you also forgot to ask a question?

Comment: I guess the question is, does the length of the support matter in this instance? From a mechanical perspective, is it just the thickness of the joint that connects from the wall to the shelf or does the length also impact the support.

Comment: In the end I built the 6 shelves. 2 with the longer supports and 4 with the shorter (had no choice as couldn't source any more of the longer supports. The shelving is now fully loaded with large sets of heavy books (`40+kg) and no issues yet or even deflection.

Comment: I agree the description was cryptic. Would be easier if I could upload some pictures though :)